# Quickbox failed push notifications on testflight and production

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, push, quickblox

Push notifications stopped working in Production and then Tesflight (after checking). They do work though if the phone is running a build from xcode. 
The error returned is BadDeviceToken.

Any advice on what to look for. I have resubmitted a new certificate on quickblox to no avail.

Comment: Please create an issue on [github](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk) and specify application ID.

Comment: I upgraded to the latest QB SDK and it works now.